# How to identify records based on most recent scan

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, greatest-n-per-group

Using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I need to identify 'JobNumber' if any of the 'item_code_1' was scanned within last 2 hours only. 'item_code_1' contains 'JobNumber' day # and sequence number.

Table1

```
JobNumber |Item_code_1   |Scanned|
12345     |12345_01_01   |Y      |
12345     |12345_01_02   |Y      |
12345     |12345_01_03   |Y      |
1234567   |1234567_01_01 |Y      |
1234567   |1234567_01_02 |Y      |
1234567   |1234567_01_03 |Y      |
```

Table2 (CURRENT TIME = 2016-02-08 16:52:32.547)

```
Scanned_date_time            |Item_Code_1  |
2016-02-08 16:52:32.547      |12345_01_01  |
2016-02-08 16:52:32.547      |12345_01_02  |
2016-02-08 16:52:32.547      |12345_01_03  |
2016-02-08 **13**:52:32.547  |1234567_01_01|
2016-02-08 **13**:52:32.547  |1234567_01_02|
2016-02-08 **13**:52:32.547  |1234567_01_03|
```

See in this case:

`JobNumber 1234567 item_code_1` was scanned more than 2 hours ago.

I only want to see the JobNumber if it's (at least 1) item_code_1 was scanned within the last two hours based on `Scanned_date_time`

Comment: Have you tried anything?  This seems like a `where` clause.

Comment: There is no JobNumber 123456 anywhere in your listed data.  You only have 12345 and 1234567.

Comment: i meant to say 1234567

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` clause. You can use another unit (my example is in seconds) if it needs to be more precise.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.item_code1 = t2.item_code_1
WHERE DATEDIFF(ss, scanned_date_time, getdate()) < 7200
```

Comment: I tried this, but I am not getting expected result. I think it's the formatting. you have used ss. when I go to the table and go to Scanned_date_time column I see data like this. 2016-03-28 21:33:43.953    :(

Comment: @BinitPatel ss is just seconds. You can change it to whatever unit you want. Your format appears to be datetime which is fine.